# Multiple complex parameters in a REST post call

Tags: rest

This is a blindspot in my understanding of REST.  I understand how to make get calls (and Post) if the call is simple, and requires maybe a few parameters.  Example:

```
https:\\randomAPI\get\coats\size:12\length:8
```

But what if I need to update a resource, and the request calls for multiple parameters, some of which may be objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically POST a JSON or XML document with more complex data.

Comment: How would that look in a url string?  Would it be a link to a JSON or XML document?

Comment: The JSON (or XML) would be the body of the request that you POST

Comment: @DmainEvent A URL doesn't include document data, it is the location of the resource on a network. You might use a query string to filter the data you get back, but these parameters are not data of the document. For example you don't put "get" into the URL. GET is the command in the HTTP header. You GET a resource by sending the verb GET to a particular URL. `GET https:\\randomAPI\coats?size=12&length=8`

Comment: Good point.  I think I got a little to overeager in my design

Answer (score 0):

Best way to pass multiple complex object to webapi services is by using tuple other than dynamic, json string, custom class.

```
HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://Server/WebService/Controller/ServiceMethod?number=" + number + "&name=" + name, Tuple.Create(args1, args2, args3, args4));

[HttpPost]
[Route("ServiceMethod")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult ServiceMethod(int number, string name, Tuple<Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4> args)
{
    Class1 c1 = (Class1)args.Item1;
    Class2 c2 = (Class2)args.Item2;
    Class3 c3 = (Class3)args.Item3;
    Class4 c4 = (Class4)args.Item4;
    /* do your actions */
    return Ok();
}
```

No need to serialize and deserialize passing object while using tuple. If you want to send more than seven complex object create internal tuple object for last tuple argument.

Comment: Sometimes I look back at questions I have asked and cringe!!!  How could I have been so stupid.  I think I have the hang of Rest now in 3 Languages, .net, java, python.